# Spring: How can I log the PageNotFound exception in a database?

Tags: spring-mvc

I would like to log when the spring fails to find a request handler because, for instance, a client tries to access our REST service with a misspelled required parameter.

What's the recommended way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think it will look something like this:

```
 @ExceptionHandler  
 @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
 public String handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
 //log your error
  return "error.jsp"; /* use the correct view name */
}
```

Hope it will give you right direction

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for: the method annotated with @ExceptionHandler must be in a controller and will be used to catche the exceptions thrown in that controller. I want to catch the PageNotFound error that happens because the url cannot be mapped to any controller.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is if you subclass `DispatcherServlet` and override the `noHandlerFound` method. You can then do whatever you wish with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I've just forward all 404 errors to one of Spring controllers (excerpt from `web.xml`):

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

And implemented appropriate logic in this controller (see [NotFoundErrorController.java](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) as example).